# GDB automatically load Python Script

Tags: python, gdb

I'm trying to setup a system where I can add python scripts to a directory, and the next time I load `gdb` they will be accessible *(the point being to place this in version control and allow other engineers simple access to my helper scripts)*.  For starters I've written a `hello.py` file, and when I type **`source /path/to/hello.py`** in `gdb`, and then type `hello` it works as expected.

How do I make GDB do this automatically?  The documentation suggests using the data-directory, and placing scripts in `data-directory/python/gdb/command`.  Placing my `hello.py` file in this directory does nothing though (however it does end up creating a `hello.pyc` file).

I've additionally tried adding this directory to my directory listing with `dir /path/to/hello/` and then hoping to be able to type `source hello.py` but this also fails.

Comment: What do you mean by automatically? Do you mean to load all Python scripts in a given directory? Or current directory? Or something else?

Answer (score 9):

Make a `.gdbinit` file, and put all your `source` commands in there in the same directory where you'll be starting `gdb` from. I believe the file will look something like this:

**.gdbinit**

```
source /path/to/hello.py
source /path/to/foobar.py
etc, etc
```

[reference](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Startup.html)

EDIT: Including the `.gdbinit` file in your version control will make sure that the files are included, independent of the global `gdb` settings.

Comment: Thanks. That does work, but I was hoping there was something that could do this in a more automated fashion.  This requires manually adding each script to the .gdbinit, plus including a full path (my attempts to source a python file without the full path result in bizarre errors).  I suppose I could have a bash script that automatically generates a .gdbinit file and passes all the paths based on where the user has setup their version control, but I was hopeful the GDB designers put hooks in for something like this.

Comment: Maybe you could add the generation of .gdbinit to your Makefile? I agree, it's too bad there's not a clean way of doing it (that I know of).

Comment: I feel like I must be missing something simple.  In particular the last line about the data-directory [here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Python.html). But having a second person unclear helped me make up a hackish solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I was looking for an answer to the same question today.  Eventually I came up with the following:

**.gdbinit**

```
python
import glob

python_dir = "/path/to/python"

# Search the python dir for all .py files, and source each
py_files = glob.glob("%s/*.py" % python_dir)
for py_file in py_files:
    gdb.execute('source %s' % py_file)
end
```

Note that `.gdbinit` can be `~/.gdbinit` or `./.gdbinit`; see [`gdbinit(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/gdbinit.5.html).

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to set `auto-load` on using the following command:

```
set auto-load python-scripts on
```

**Reference**: http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Python-Auto_002dloading.html#Python-Auto_002dloading

Comment: I saw that, but whenever I try typing that (either in gdb, or putting it in my .gdbinit) it gives me the error: "on" or "off" expected.  I think it is just calling whatever it does for "auto-load" and passing that "python-scripts".

Answer (score 1):

It seems there must be a better way, but for now I did the following.  To .gdbinit I added:`source /path/to/setup_python.py`

Then I wrote the file setup_python.py as:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import glob
import os

# Search the python dir for all .py files, and source each
setup_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
python_dir = os.path.join(setup_dir, "python")
py_files = glob.glob("%s/*.py" % python_dir)

for py_file in py_files:
    gdb.execute('source %s' % py_file)
```

This will source all files in the python sub-directory, and both setup_python.py and those files can be checked into source control.

Comment: This is genius!!

Comment: Sadly, doesn't work if your files are dependent on one another.

Answer (score 0):

Different, but similar problem:  I tell everyone that in their home directory "~/.gdbinit" file they must load one common python module via an absolute path.
This is exactly one line, not something complicated.

You should note: Some would call this a security threat, It is a balancing act - I have to trust my team, they have to trust me. I think of it this way: we all work with sharp-pointy things, we must be knowledgeable of what we are doing. Every team is unique, use your judgement.

I also have to deal with multiple versions of GDB but a common single .gdbinit file.  Example; AndroidOLD(GDB), AndroidNEW(GDB), LinuxHost(GDB), and SomeOther(GDB)

People switch between projects using different things through out the day, common script directory problem. And I have my own scripts in my home directory

I depend upon GDB-Python extensions

```
import os
import gdb
```

On Linux, I can determine the *exact* version of GDB by looking at the absolute path to the executable hence:  AndroidOLD(gdb) vrs AndroidNEW(gdb) can be determined by looking for a version number in the path.

```
exename = os.readlink( '/proc/self/exe' )
```

I can also use these items to determine the host type(cygwin, linux, mac, etc), and more details about the target architecture (ie: Which android cpu target?)

```
print (gdb.HOST_CONFIG)
# gives: x86_64-linux-gnu
# Alternates: MACOS, or CYGWIN32 or CYGWIN64
print (gdb.TARGET_CONFIG)
# Gives: 64bit android, 32bit android, or something else
```

Now, more to the original posters question:  A common directory with lots of scripts

1. I have multiple "common directories"
2. And I have to deal with different architectures
3. And my people switch between projects
4. And switch between versions

Some project systems have a common root directory (ie: Android) for the project or module, and all sub components are sub directories of that common directory. Using python - you can start with the current directory, then climb up the directory tree one at a time until you find some magic file that tells you more (for example some file that identifies the root directory of an android build)

now that I know all of that, I can iterate over the files I need to load via:

```
import gdb
gdb.execute('source %s' % filename)
```

Problem solved.